# Finding alternative to a deprecated method

Tags: java, android, tabs, deprecated

I'm using the TabLayout in my android app. I need to change the tabIndicatorHeight to a larger one.
So far, this is how I'm achieving it:

[image]

[image]

As you can see the method is deprecated and looking over its documentation, both on the Class itself and [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html#setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(int)), I cannot find any alternative.

How can I get the currently used method or for any other deprecated methods in general?

[image]

Comment: Seems like you're looking at the wrong docs for the library you're using. Have a look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout.html#setSelectedTabIndicatorHeight(int)). Quoting: "This method is deprecated. If possible, set the intrinsic height directly on a custom indicator drawable passed to [`setSelectedTabIndicator(Drawable)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/tabs/TabLayout.html#setSelectedTabIndicator(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable))."

Answer (score -2):

Try to set `app:tabIndicatorHeight` value for TabLayout in xml